# Use Arkime to read and process packets from kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, tcp, packet-capture

We have huge amount of custom packets with different size and length in Kafka topics. about 1 GigB/s.
we want read this packets, process and then store useful part of data in elastic.
is it possible to get and read this packets with Arkime (I now the Arkime used for PCAP types) if no could you recommend another solution?

Comment: What do you define as useful? Wireshark can read kafka network traffic, so there's no reason you couldn't use something else, (what have you tried?) but kafka itself can't hold data larger than 1MB per record, by default.

Comment: this means that some part of the packet content doesn't important for us so we want only find the specific part of message in packet and extract it, then store result in database. ok?

Comment: Okay. What specific issues are you running into running tcpdump for Kafka clients and loading that into some tool?